# jQuery: delete a section if it does not have a specific class

Tags: jquery

There is something like this markup:

```html
<section id="school_section" class="several classes and the class termid_[some number here]">
    <section class="several classes and the class termid_5 school_course_section"></section>
    <section class="several classes and the class termid_8 school_course_section"></section>
    <section class="several classes and the class termid_1 school_course_section"></section>
</section>
```

It is necessary to get the `termid_` of the main section. Compare the classes of child sections with the received class from the main section and if there is no such class, then hide them.

For example, if `section#school_section` contains the `termid_8` class, then in this example need to hide the `termid_5` and `termid_1` sections.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    var current_termID = $('#school_section').attr('class').match(/(?:\s|^)termid_(\d+)/)[1];
    if ($('.school_course_section').hasClass(current_termID) == '') {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

I've done something like this, but so far it's not working as expected.

I will be grateful for any help)

Comment: You're setting `current_termID` to just the number, not the whole class. Use `[0]` to get the whole match. You can also use `\b` to match a word boundary instead of `\s|^`

Comment: Why are you not just selecting it by the class?

Comment: `$(this)` is the whole document, not a specific `.school_course_section`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[0]` to get the entire match, which includes the `termid_` prefix.

The `if` statement just tells you if there are any elements with the matching class, it doesn't select them. Use `current_termID` in a selector to select the matching elements and call `.hide()` on that.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var current_termID = $('#school_section').attr('class').match(/\btermid_\d+/)[0];
  $(`.school_course_section:not(.${current_termID})`).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="school_section" class="several classes and the class termid_8">
  <section class="several classes and the class termid_5 school_course_section">class 5</section>
  <section class="several classes and the class termid_8 school_course_section">class 8</section>
  <section class="several classes and the class termid_1 school_course_section">class 1</section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the term from the class. Use that to filter out the ones that match. Hide the others

```js
var elem = $("#school_section");
const term = elem[0].className.match(/(termid_\d+)/);
elem.children().not("." + term).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="school_section" class="several classes and the class termid_8">
  <section class="several classes and the class termid_5 school_course_section">5</section>
  <section class="several classes and the class termid_8 school_course_section">8</section>
  <section class="several classes and the class termid_1 school_course_section">1</section>
</section>
```